# IPv4 and IPv6 HTTP request javascript

Tags: javascript, koa

I am doing some HTTP request and I'm having a problem cause i'm getting the IP address as follow: ::ffff:198.0.0.1

I tried to remove the ::ffff part by using

```
if (ip.substr(0, 7) == "::ffff:") {
   ip = ip.substr(7)
}
```

and it does make my code work but I think it's not the best solution. Can anyone advice me on what would be the best practice? I'm using Koa JS.

EDIT:
I'm not really familiar with IPv4 and IPv6 but basically, I'm making a post request to http://198.0.0.1:8000/send_request. So the IP that I was getting is ::ffff:198.0.0.1 and if that happens, I don't successfully send a post request. However, if I just use 198.0.0.1, then my request is successful

Comment: Just a little side note ```::ffff:127.0.0.1``` is a valid ipv6 address

Comment: *"...and I'm having a problem cause i'm getting the IP address as follow: ::ffff:127.0.0.1..."* What problem is that causing? As @dotoconnor points out, [it's a perfectly valid IPv6 address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv4-mapped_IPv6_addresses) (an IPv6 mapping of the IPv4 loopback address).

Answer (score 0):

Koa listens by default to IPv6, if you are in a pure IPv4 network and only need to listen to the IPv4 address, you can use the following configuration:

```
app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0');
```

Then you can get a clean IPv4 address via `ctx.ip`.